# Hosting web (Hello World) in Google Compute Engine VM (free trial) + Apache + Ajax + php + javascript

Tags: php, ajax, google-api, google-compute-engine

The implementation on Google Compute Engine VM (free trial) of Hello World has the following files:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function create () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"firestoreData.php",    //the page containing php script
            type: "POST",    //request type,
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                console.log("error:" + exception);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="create()">Click Me</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

firestoreData.php:

```
<?php
return "hello world";
```

The problem is that the response of Ajax is the content of the php file:

```
<?php
return "hello world";
```

See the image[1]

I've tried with several ways of php files with the same result:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

...

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
exit;
```

...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbpWb.png

Comment: Ok, so what do you get if you directly access the php file in the URL.

Comment: Once you have done that, you need to see if you have PHP enabled.

Comment: if I access directly to the php file in the url I get the same, the content of the php file. I installed php in my VM. What you mean that I need to enabled?

Comment: You're right!!!! @TimBrownlaw !!!! please post the answer I'd like to vote you!

Comment: Thanks but It's more meaningful if you show what you did to enable it, IF it's something that someone else might miss and needs to perform to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Following TimBrownlaw's suggestion the problem was resolved enabling php7(version installed in my VM) as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```